# How to read Json string in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to integrate some data from json, I was able to save the json file as String, but I can't read whay I need form it. 
from the json below I need to get the firstname and the lastname to save it on my java object of type Contact.

```
{
  "form-submissions": [
    {
      "portal-id": 62515.0,
      "page-title": "Testing!",
      "title": "Test Form",
      "timestamp": 1.33830544E12,
      "conversion-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110",
      "page-url": "http: //www.example.com/test/Default.aspx?RewriteStatus\u003d1",
      "page-id": "807831",
      "form-id": "4320"
    }
  ],
  "identity-profiles": [
    {
      "identities": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.33830544E12,
          "type": "LEAD_GUID",
          "value": "8a5c2ed0379938020137993893d40013"
        },
        {
          "timestamp": 1.33830544E12,
          "type": "EMAIL",
          "value": "test@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "vid": 71.0
    },
    {
      "identities": [],
      "vid": 59.0
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "lifecyclestage": {
      "value": "lead",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305450005E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "lead",
          "source-type": "MIGRATION",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_first_timestamp": {
      "value": "1337815228837",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "1337815228837",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_source_data_1": {
      "value": "",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "firstname": {
      "value": "Test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "FirstName",
          "value": "Test",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_last_url": {
      "value": "http: //www.example.com/test/",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "http: //www.example.com/test/",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_source_data_2": {
      "value": "",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "lastname": {
      "value": "Contact",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "LastName",
          "value": "Contact",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "createdate": {
      "value": "1338305440000",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "1338305440000",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_num_page_views": {
      "value": "3",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "3",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_last_timestamp": {
      "value": "1337815238097",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "1337815238097",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "phone": {
      "value": "555-555-2262",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "Phone",
          "value": "555-555-2262",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_last_referrer": {
      "value": "http: //www.example.com/test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "http: //www.example.com/test",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "field_text_7": {
      "value": "62515",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "HubSpotPortal(Hub)ID",
          "value": "62515",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_first_referrer": {
      "value": "",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_first_url": {
      "value": "http: //www.example.com/support/",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "http: //www.example.com/support/",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_num_visits": {
      "value": "1",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "1",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    },
    "field_text_9": {
      "value": "test",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "CustomFormQuestion",
          "value": "test",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "field_text_8": {
      "value": "about20",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "HowManyHubSpotUsers?",
          "value": "about20",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ipaddress": {
      "value": "71.172.15.18",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "71.172.15.18",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "email": {
      "value": "test@example.com",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.338305440003E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "Email",
          "value": "test@example.com",
          "source-type": "FORM",
          "source-id": "bc65112f47c2469e90f5951213a66110"
        }
      ]
    },
    "hs_analytics_source": {
      "value": "DIRECT_TRAFFIC",
      "versions": [
        {
          "timestamp": 1.337817901004E12,
          "selected": false,
          "source-label": "None",
          "value": "DIRECT_TRAFFIC",
          "source-type": "ANALYTICS",
          "source-id": "None"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "vid": 71.0
}
```

I was trying to use `com.google.gson.Gson`; to directly match the value but no luck:

```
CrmContacts contact = gson.fromJson(jsonString, CrmContacts.class);
```

The CrmContacts class:

```
public class CrmContacts {
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
}
```

Comment: `firstname` and `lastname` is Object not a `String`. What are you expecting?

Comment: how could you possible map this automatically...I suggest you write your own converter with jsonPath..

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Actually, Gson is very good at automatically mapping JSON to Java. However, these objects don't really match. OP: if you want to continue using Gson, help it understand how to parse your JSON.

Comment: @keyser I didn't say it is not possible to automatically map json to java object, in his case, it is kind of unpossible to map this json to the object he's expecting...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Yeah I know, I just didn't want OP to get the wrong impression. You steered him away from Gson.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is my first time working with Json, I was trying with more simple json files, and the gson.fromJson(jsonString, CrmContacts.class); was going great. but with json data like this I wasn't sure if the gson is still a valid option here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create exact replica of JSON string into Java POJO classes or `Map`

Here is simple code to get the `firstname` and `lastname` from `properties`

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

// JSON string to Java Map object
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
Map<String,Object> properties=(Map<String,Object>)data.get("properties");

Object lastname = properties.get("lastname");
Object firstname = properties.get("firstname");

// convert Object into JSON string back
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(lastname));
```

You need to spend some time on reading [GSON library](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)